# SOLVED read comments :: AttributeError: 'databaseWindow' object has no attribute 'menu' , in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Im trying to add a MDDropDownMenu in my databaseWindow, but each time I try to access the menu, the app crashes with an error of *"'databaseWindow' object has no attribute 'menu'"*. Im planning to use the dropdown menu as a list of options for the user to choose from so they can run a query. Im new to KivyMD and any assistance would be appreciated.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import mysql.connector



class myLoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class databaseWindow(Screen):
    def dbtable_menu(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        menu_items = [
          {
           "text": f"Item {i}",
           "right_text": f"R+{i}",
           "right_icon": "apple-keyboard-command",
           "left_icon": "git",
           "viewclass": "Item",
           "height": dp(54),
           "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(x),
          } for i in range(5)
        ]
       self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
          caller = self.manager.get_screen('database1').ids['button'], 
          items = menu_items,
          width_mult=4,
        )
       self.add_widget(self.menu)
   
    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        print(text_item)
        self.manager.get_screen('database1').ids['button'].text = str(text_item)



class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_file('login3.kv')
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(myLoginScreen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(databaseWindow(name='database1'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Here is the kivy file:

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#:import utils kivy.utils
ScreenManager:
    myLoginScreen:
    databaseWindow:
<myLoginScreen>:
    id:main
    name:'main'
    bg_color: (1,1,1,.3)
    highlight_color1jbsidis: [0,0,0,0]
    highlight_color2jbsidis: (0,0,0,.3)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0A609E')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    FloatLayout:
        #Image: 
        #    source: '/Users/logo.png'
        #    pos_hint: {'right':.99, 'top':.85}
        #    size_hint_y: None
        #    height: dp(40)
        #    size: self.size 
        #    pos: self.pos
        #    allow_stretch: False
        #     keep_ratio: True
        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
            foreground_color: [1,1,1,1]
            background_color: [0,0,0,0]
            background_image: ""
            background_normal: ""
            background_active: ""
            multiline: False
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: .7 ,.1 #.06
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.65} #'center_y':.8
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1,1,1,.5]
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: 10,
        FloatLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                text: "[u]Reset password[/u]"
                icon: 'account'
                markup: True
                color: Window.clearcolor
                opposite_colors: True
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y':.65}    
        TextInput:
            id: password
            hint_text: "Password"
            foreground_color: [1,1,1,1]
            background_color: [0,0,0,0]
            background_image: ""
            background_normal: ""
            background_active: ""
            multiline: False
            password: True
            size_hint: .7 ,.1 #.06
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.45}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1,1,1,.5]
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: 10,
        FloatLayout:
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'lock-outline'
                markup: True
                color: Window.clearcolor
                opposite_colors: True
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y':.45}
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: sign_button
            text: "Sign In"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": .3}
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "database1"
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: button
            text: "Sign up"
            size_hint: .2 ,.05
            pos_hint: {"right": .85, "center_y": .1}
            opacity: 1
            disabled: False
            bg_color: (0,0,0,1)
            color: [0,0,0,1]  
<databaseWindow>:
    id: database1
    name: 'database1'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0A609E')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button
        text: "PRESS ME"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5, "center_y":0.5}
        on_release: root.menu.open()

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Select ONLY 1 Row for Query"
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        elevation: 5
        
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: 'logout-variant'
            on_press: 
                app.root.current = 'main'
                root.log_out()

# GUI for pop up window
<P>:
    Label:
        text : "Please enter valid information"
        size_hint : 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint : {"x" : 0.3, "top" : 0.8}
```

Comment: By the time you press the button `self.menu` is not even defined...

Comment: Thank you for the input, but if i'm following you, if I replace the `root.menu.open()` argument from the databaseWindow "on_realease" argument to `root.dbtable_menu.open()` I'd be on the right track

Comment: SOLVED IT: 
Under variable `menu_items`  the parameter `"viewclass" : "Item"` will need to be changed to `"viewclass": "OneLineListItem"`. (seems `"Item"` is no longer an option).

Comment: NEXT: in the `dbtable_menu` function  add `self.menu.open()`

Comment: Then in the kivy file change the `on_release:` to the following `on_release: root.dbtable_menu()`